# Numpy evaluation order

Tags: python, numpy, in-place

As I was looking at some issues related to how Numpy indexing works (sometimes a view, sometimes a copy), I encountered an example in the Numpy docs, which baffles me a bit.  Specifically, it can be found [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Very simplistically, I don't understand the reason why the following snippet

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2)
x[[0, 0]] += 1
print(x)
```

produces the result that it does.

I understand that the reason you get what you get is that `x[[0, 0]] += 1` seems to expand to something like `x.setitem(x.getitem([0, 0]).iadd(1))`, but I don't understand why that's the case (you can test that this is what happens if you subclass `ndarray` and add messages to the relevant methods).

Given the precedence rules, isn't the statement `x[[0, 0]] += 1` first converted to `x[[0, 0]] = x[[0, 0]] + 1`, which means the subsequent expansion should look more like`x.getitem([0, 0]).setitem(x.getitem([0, 0]).iadd(1))`?  I appreciate that this would be awkward, but I don't really understand the formal logic that produces the expansion that allows the modification of the original array.

Is there an implicit binding that takes precedence over subscription?

I tried

```
import numpy as np

class A(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("getitem")
        r = np.ndarray.__getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return r
    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("setitem")
        r = np.ndarray.__setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return r 
    def __iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("iadd")
        r = np.ndarray.__iadd__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return r

nd = np.arange(2)
x = nd.view(A)
x[[0, 0]] += 1
print(x)
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html

Comment: Are you puzzled by the [0,0] case only, or also by something like [0,1] selection?

Comment: I am not puzzled by the indexing itself, as that's a numpy implementation detail.  I am puzzled by the specific logic that the interpreter uses to produce the result.

Comment: You got it right the first time - get, add, set.  The `__setitem___` method includes the necessary `get` logic.  The distinction between view and copy does not apply during `set`.  All the interpeter does is call the methods; the actual work is in those class specific methods, whether the class is integer, list, or numpy array.

Comment: I know I got it right, since I can see that it's what happens.  However, what I don't understand is why!  Also, the distinction between view and copy does not apply during `set`, but it does during `get` and it determines whether the original array element gets incremented once or more than once (this is also pointed out in the documentation for the ufunc at that you helpfully linked to).

Comment: That `.at` explains that the `get/add` step is done in a new buffer.  That is then assigned back.  That's internal to numpy, so trying to find an alternative interpreter sequence won't help.  That `.at` doc is the best explanation that python level  programmers get.

Comment: I understand and agree that the `get/add` step is applied to a copy that is created by Numpy's "advanced indexing".  That is made completely clear by the docs.  I still don't understand how and why the assignment happens, which is NOT explained by the docs and appears to me to contradict the interpreter's own syntax rules (see my followup).  Again, you're right, it is what it is, but I am only trying to understand, in hopes of becoming a wee bit wiser in the process.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging makes it even more puzzling, as far as I am concerned.

I used ast to look at what the interpreter does with the following block:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(2)
x[[0, 0]] += 1
```

The full output is:

```
("Module(body=[Import(names=[alias(name='numpy', asname='np')]), "
 "Assign(targets=[Name(id='x', ctx=Store())], "
 "value=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='np', ctx=Load()), attr='arange', "
 'ctx=Load()), args=[Constant(value=2)], keywords=[])), '
 "AugAssign(target=Subscript(value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), "
 'slice=List(elts=[Constant(value=0), Constant(value=0)], ctx=Load()), '
 'ctx=Store()), op=Add(), value=Constant(value=1))], type_ignores=[])')
```

The line that shows the expansion of `x[[0,0]] += 1`, formatted to the best of my ability, is:

```
AugAssign(
    target=Subscript(
            value=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), 
            slice=List(elts=[Constant(value=0), Constant(value=0)], ctx=Load()),
            ctx=Store()
    ), 
    op=Add(), 
    value=Constant(value=1)
)
```

So, based on this, the target for the AugAssign should be the result of the Subscript operation, so how does it end up being `x.setitem(x.getitem([0, 0]).iadd(1))` ?  This still doesn't make sense...

Comment: I don't know the details of `AugAssign` for `numpy` (beyond what `ufunc.at` tells us).  PEP203, proposed in for py2, sums it up: `The object x is loaded, then y is added to it, and the resulting object is stored back in the original place. The precise action performed on the two arguments depends on the type of x, and possibly of y.`

Comment: The `type of x` is important.  `+=` works for numbers, lists, and strings (but not tuples), all of which define a '+' operation.  But the details differ.  `numpy` arrays are distinct in that they allow 'duplicate' indexing, e.g. `[0,0]`, so behavior of the other types gives us few hints of what to exptect.  The key point is that `+=` is not implemented as a loop: `for i in [0,0]: x[i]+=1`.  The "vectorized' behavior of arrays is implemented by their own methods, not by the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally have a full understanding...

Numpy documentation which describes how advanced indexing creates copies, rather than views, refers to cases where an expression such as `x[[1, 2]]` is used in the context of a reference (i.e. it is on the right-hand side).  As the same docs specifically mention [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html#indexing-operations),

> "...during the assignment of `x[[1, 2]]` no view or copy is
> created..."

While this is kinda helpful, the reasoning is not given.  However, it can be found in the Python reference docs for basic assignment statements [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).  The specific logic that the documentation describes for subscriptions and slicings explains why there is no copy created when `x[[1, 2]]` is the assignment target (is on the left-hand side).